# Mysql Agregate function to select maximum and then select minimum price within that group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to get the maximum value out of a aggregate function, and then also get the min value out of a Price column which comes back in results.

```
id | discount | price 
 1 |       60 |   656 
 2 |       60 |   454 
 3 |       60 |   222 
 4 |       30 |   335 
 5 |       30 |   333 
 6 |       10 |   232
```

So in above table, I would like to separate Minimum Price vs Highest Discount. 
This is the result I should be seeing:

```
id | discount | price 
 3 |       60 |   222 
 5 |       30 |   333 
 6 |       10 |   232
```

As you can see, its taken discount=60 group and separated the lowest price - 222, and the same for all other discount groups.

Could someone give me the SQL for this please, something like this -

```
SELECT MAX(discount) AS Maxdisc
     , MIN(price) as MinPrice
     , 
  FROM mytable 
 GROUP 
    BY discount
```

However, this doesnt separate the minimum price for each group. I think i need to join this table to itself to achieve that. Also, the table contains milions of rows, so the sql needs to be fast. One flat table.

Comment: This query would result in a syntax error.

Comment: ...and you're not interested in the max discount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is asked and answered with tedious regularity in SO. If only the algorithm was better at spotting duplicates. Anyway...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT discount,MIN(price) min_price FROM my_table GROUP BY discount) y 
    ON y.discount = x.discount 
   AND y.min_price = x.price;
```

Comment: This is looking good. I didnt ask my original question properly, as I have another column called "hotel" which contains hotelIDs. So for each hotel, I need to get the highest discount and within that discount group the lowest price.

Also, stackoverflows algorithms are as good as google's when it comes to this question - asking a question includes so many keywords that google doesnt know what to offer in its results...

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you cannot `group by discount` and then `maximize the discount` value.

This should get you the result you are looking for..

```
SELECT Max(ID) AS ID, discount, MIN(price) as MinPrice, FROM mytable GROUP BY discount
```

Comment: This is incorrect, I do not need Max(ID), why would you put this in?

Comment: Your sample data and results suggests that `max(id)` might be how the `id` is calculated.  You don't really specify how it is done.  My guess is that you want the id on the row with the minimum price.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the `id`, yo would do:

```
select discount, min(price) as minprice
from table t
group by discount;
```

If you want other columns in the row, you can either join back to the original table or use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select substring_index(group_concat(id order by price), ',', 1) as id,
       discount, min(price)
from table t
group by discount;
```

This will not always work because the intermediate result for `group_concat()` can overflow if there are too many matches within a column.  This is controlled by a system parameter, which could be made bigger if necessary.